# How to lookup data in excel and return value next to it?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, excel-formula

**My Excel data:**

[Excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FU674.png)

**What Im I doing?**

I have been looking into `pandas`, `openpyxl` all sorts of modules. Not sure how to assemble a script to do me a `vlookup()` function.

What I am trying to do is, give a variable of `find_string = "John"` and use it to look inside the sheet and return me `Last Name` connected on the same row as the `First Name` of `John`.

**Example**

```
find_string = "John"

return value of John = West
```

because John and West are on the same row but different column.

How can this be done?

**This is what I got to..**

```
import pandas as pd

file = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/test/Excel file.xlsx'

find_string = "John"

x = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = 'Sheet2')
```

**UPDATE FROM AN ANSWER**
Return value:

[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kge1w.jpg)

```
file = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/test/Excel file.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = 'sheet2')
 new_df = df[df['First Name'].str.contains('John')][['Last Name']].reset_index(drop = True)
```

I need to return just the word `West`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include at least one of your attempts to use either (or both) of those modules.

Comment: @martineau edited my original question. There's only minimal code from me, just not sure where to head from here.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help much with pandas-related questions, but think you're more likely to get help now. Suggest you dig into the documentation and/or search for related questions here.

Comment: @martineau no worries, thank you for your kind suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific case, you can just use the pandas Series.str.contains().  The documentation is on this link https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html.  For your specific example, something like this could suffice.

```
file = 'C:/Users/user/Desktop/test/Excel file.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = 'sheet2')
new_df = df[df['First Name'].str.contains('John')]
```

Comment: How would I return the 2nd column on it own?

Comment: Sorry, can you rephrase that?

Comment: If you mean, you want only the 2nd column as a dataframe, it would just be this: new_df = df[df['First Name'].str.contains('John')][['Last Name']].reset_index(drop = True)

Comment: the output of your code is great. It returns me `Headers, index, all values` how can i return one value from column 2? as an example return me just `West`

Comment: I have edited my question, image below of my current output, its shows index and header, how do i get the last name just to show?

Comment: I have tried `print(new_df[0])` but that does not work

Comment: Try `x = str(new_df).split()[2]` and `print(x)` this should return you just `West`

Comment: If you are referring to this exact example,  then it would be this: list(new_df['Last Name'])[0]